# Does Yawn work if it is executed in Mist field but later the field is changed?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Suppose that the following case (the field is Mist in Double Battle):

1. Slowking used Yawn to Garchomp.
2. In the next turn, the opponent withdraws a Pokèmon and summons Tapu Lele, and the field is now changed.

In this case, does Garchomp fall to asleep after the end of the second turn?

Or how about the opposite case - that is, Yawn is executed in non-misty field but later the field is changed to Mist before the effect of Yawn is activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mist prevents the use of Yawn, so your first scenario wouldn't work.

In your second scenario, Mist would prevent the Pokémon from falling asleep.

Comment: @Blaszard Depends on what you mean by verified